# Java 8: pass method reference to another method

Tags: java, java-8

I make myself familiar with Java 8's so called `method references`.

Two questions:

1) I want to println uppercased values. How can I pass the result of `String::toUpperCase` to `println`? For example this block of code doesn't compile:

```
List<String> food = Arrays.asList("apple", "banana", "mango", "orange", "ice");
food.forEach(System.out.println(String::toUpperCase));
```

2) Is there something similar to anonymous function parameters (`_`) like is Scala?

Comment: What do you mean, "the result of a method reference?" `println` is a void method, so obviously you can't pass its result to `forEach`.

Comment: I want to print uppercased values. So I want to combine toUpperCase with println

Comment: "Nice" to get a vote down without explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is to combine a *function* with a consumer.

You can do it this way:

```
food.stream().map(String::toUpperCase).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Alternatively you can use a lambda expression:

```
food.forEach(x->System.out.println(x.toUpperCase()));
```

---

Besides these straight-forward approaches, you can combine *functions* to create a new function but not a function with a consumer, however, with the following quirky code you can do it:

```
Function<String,String>     f0=String::toUpperCase;
food.forEach(f0.andThen(" "::concat).andThen(System.out::append)::apply);
```

This get even uglier if you try to inline the first expression for a one-liner…

Comment: The `Stream` *is* the way how to combine arbitrary operations.

Comment: Well, [`_` is a reserved keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523946/underscore-is-a-reserved-keyword/23525446#23525446) and might be a placeholder for parameters you don’t want to use in a future Java version, however, that doesn’t apply here as here the parameters *are* used.