# Why do I get "as of release 9, '_' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier" error when using a single underscore variable name?

Tags: java, java-8, javac, java-9

Why do I get "as of release 9, '_' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier" error when using a single underscore variable name?

This happens when compiling Java code with javac version 8.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523946/underscore-is-a-reserved-keyword/23525446

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. What is the exact version you're using? And IDE or just command line?

Comment: Because it is going to be a reserved keyword? For what purposes?

Comment: @yuku If you are familiar with Scala, the underscore is used for various cases such as an anonymous function placeholder (see example above). Maybe in a future release we will be able to do something along the lines of `Stream.of(1, 2, 3).map( _ + 2)` which would result in a Stream of 3, 4, 5. Since it's not very common to use only an underscore as an identifier, I think it's fair to prevent that it will have a special meaning in the future releases.

Comment: @ZouZou: [It won’t be like Scala](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-July/010670.html) or well, let’s call it unlikely (never say never).