# What is the use of Java 9 new underscore ("_") keyword?

Tags: java

In Java 9, underscore was marked as a keyword. All blog posts just say that will throw an error when used. But for what reasons it was made a keyword, and what is the use of it now, or maybe in future?

Comment: lol. the duplicated post, does not answer my question ))

Comment: The answer ist 'phase 2' mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51254912/4308751, no?

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23525446/6395627) explains that `_` is reserved for possible future use. The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51254912/6395627) explains one potential future use is for unused lambda parameters. Is that not satisfactory? Note that some of the comments in the duplicate Q&A also link to other related resources.

Comment: Ok, thanks, didn't saw that!