# Remove Java warnings in the VS Code PROBLEMS window

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio-code

I'm using Java in VS Code and am getting warnings in the PROBLEMS tab.

```
'_' should not be used as an identifier, since it is a reserved keyword from source level 1.8 on
Type safety: The method put(Object, Object) belongs to the raw type Hashtable. References to generic type Hashtable<K,V> should be parameterized
```

Other ones also.

How can I disable them?

There seems to be an integer identifier at the end of each message - seems to be associated with the message type.

Some people have suggested looking at the `.settings` file and add something like

`org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.missingSerialVersion=ignore`

But I haven't found something related to my warnings - is there a complete list somehwer of these eclipse problem strings.

Comment: Are you saying there is not a source file and line number with each warning?

Comment: yes there's a reference to a file and line-number. But I'd like to disable the warning.

Comment: Java warnings usually indicate that code is syntactically valid but logically incorrect.  Those two warnings, and pretty much every Java warning, are things you’re better off fixing than suppressing.

Comment: @greg-449 In VS Code the Java support is headless Eclipse via LSP. That's why this VS Code question is tagged with [eclipse].

Comment: That warning cannot be disabled since it's an compile error indicating invalid Java code.

Answer (score -3):

You'd better fix it, instead of suppress it.

The first warning: Through [this doc](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-July/010670.html), you'd better not use '_' as an identifier, otherwise you will get an warning even an error. You can also get more information from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523946/underscore-is-a-reserved-keyword) page.

The second warning is because you haven't added 'generic parameters', like this one:

```
HashMap map =newHashMap();
map.put("showOppo", option.isShowOppo());
```

And you can change like this to avoid it:

```
HashMap<String,String> map =newHashMap<>();
```

Comment: This does not answer the question asked. The question was very clear, how to suppress warnings, preferably specific warning types. There are legit reasons for wanting to suppress certain warnings, for instance in automatically generated code.