# What is the convention for variable names in lambda expressions when the variable is not used?

Tags: java, lambda, coding-style, naming-conventions, naming

I'm trying to find a name similar to what `i,j` are for loops, or `x,y` is for coordinates etc.

I have a code like this:

```
DbSetup.setupCommon(x -> HibernateHelper.addResource(SpecificEntityHelper.HIBERNATE_RESOURCE, schemaName));
```

In this case `x` is not a required variable name and I found it is used in few places in code base of our project, so probably is
Of course in this specific case I can not use a static reference to the function `HibernateHelper::addResource` and it sounds like there is no other way to not to have a name of the variable at all.

Comment: You can see from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523946/underscore-is-a-reserved-keyword) that `_` was intended to do this, but it appears to have been forgotten. A comment there suggests `$`.

Comment: It hasn't been "forgotten".  You can see from [JLS 3.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9) that it is reserved for **possible** future use.  Frankly, any single character identifier will work as well as any other one.

Comment: @StephenC: The link I posted has a link to an email that I am almost certain is the origin of JLS 3.9, and gives explicitly just one example of the those possible future uses: *things it might be used for include things like "I don't want to give this variable a name"* (pretty much exactly what this question asks about). AFAIK `_` remained "reserved for possible future uses" for almost eight years now, with none of them being implemented, so... I think "forgotten" might be an adequate description of the situation.

Comment: An alternative reading is that they thought better of that particular idea.  Reading the Brian Goetz email, the take away is that they were reclaiming `_` ... not that they had specific plans to use it.  Note given that they decided to reclaim `_`, it was best that they did it ASAP ... to stop it spreading through everyone's codebase (like `$` has done in javascript.)  The longer they left it, the harder it would have been to reclaim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Java syntax doesn't provide a way to have no identifier at all if the argument is to be ignored.

A single `_` *may* serve that purpose in the future, but as of Java 16 `_` is just a keyword that is *"reserved for possible future use in parameter declarations."*; see [JLS 3.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9).)

It is inadvisable to use `$` because all identifiers that contain `$` are reserved for use by source code generators or for legacy purposes; see [JLS 3.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9)

Also, there isn't an established conventional name for a dummy argument to a lambda expression.

---

My advice would be to just use a single letter identifier; e.g. `x`.  A lambda expression will typically be small enough that you can easily see that (say) `x` is not used in the expression.

Alternatively, you could pick a name like `unused` or `dummy` or `ignore` to flag your intent to not use the value.

Comment: Intellij suggest to use ignore in the variable name otherwise a warning is raised.